# React useEffect clean up for multiple functions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I have a useEffect that handles Firebase authentication.
When I sign out and then sign in again, I see this effect is called twice. Every time I sign out and back in, it is called an additional time.

I have a feeling I need to handle this with a clean up function, but I don't know how to write it.

Here is my hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('RUNNING THE EFFECT');
  function routeUser(user) {
    // Redirect user somewhere depending on user state
  }
  function setupUser(user: User) {
    // sets the user state object
    routeUser(user);
  }
  if (!user) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authenticatedUser) {
        callGraphQLMethod({ variables: { uid: authUser.uid, phoneNumber: authUser.phoneNumber } })
          .then(async (document) => {
            setupUser(...);
          });
      }
    });
  } else {
    // User object is already in state. use that instead
  }
  return () => {
    // >>>>>>>> How do I clean all this up?
  } 
}, [callGraphQLMethod, setUser, user]);
```

Comment: if you are setting the state inside of the Effect then it will render cause it has a new state value

Comment: But the effect is not attached to each user state. Meaning, how come I am getting increasingly more and more rerenders. If I log out and back in 100 times, this effect will run 100 times. Is that normal?

Comment: Each time the effect runs you are adding another `onAuthStateChanged` callback. You likely want to only run that part of the effect once when the component mounts. Handle the other functions in an effect with depedencies.

Comment: every time you change state in the component it will rerender and every time you change a prop of a component it will rerender (you can of course use React.memo to partially  stop this behavior in some cases if you want) but that's how reacts works if you are loading a component and then on did mount you fetch a value and set it to state It will rerender to show you the result it's normal

Comment: @DrewReese and that onAuthStateChanged lingers? is that what I need to clean up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many times functions like this return a cleanup function to unsubscribe to resources. This appears to be the case with `onAuthStateChanged` as well.

[onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged)

> ```
> onAuthStateChanged ( nextOrObserver :  Observer < any > | ( ( a : 
>   User | null ) => any ) ,  error ? :  ( a :  Error ) => any , 
>   completed ? :  firebase.Unsubscribe ) : firebase.Unsubscribe
> ```

1. Declare a variable to hold the `unsubscribe` callback function
2. Capture the return value from `onAuthStateChanged` invocation
3. Return a cleanup function from the effect to call `unsubscribe`

Updated effect with cleanup function to unsubscribe to event stream.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let unsubscribe;

  ...

  if (!user) {
    unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      ...
    });
  } else {
    ...
  }

  return () => {
    unsubscribe?.();
  } 
}, [callGraphQLMethod, setUser, user]);
```

Comment: Brilliant. Could you please explain what unsubscribe?.() does. How it's related to the onAuthStateChanged function. I know the "?" is to check if it exists, but what is ".()"?

Comment: @Ben Optional Chaining (`?.`) operator check on a function, i.e. instead of `unsubscribe && unsubscribe()` you can `unsubscribe?.()`. [Optional Chaining with function calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Optional_chaining_with_function_calls)